# shell stdout to two command and program is stuck

Tags: linux, shell, tee

I have a sample shell command to calculate array percentile number

```
$ time zcat input.txt.gz | head -n 999999 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{print $13}' | st
--percentile=97.5
75

real    0m3.532s
user    0m8.584s
sys     0m0.648s
```

Its fast you can note, because I want to calculate number with two percentile pos, I use tee to redirect stdout to to command

```
mkfifo output_txt;
zcat input.txt.gz | head -n 999999 |
   awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{print $13}' |
   tee >(st --percentile=2.5) >> output_txt |
   st --percentile=97.5 >> output_txt;
cat output_txt; rm output_txt
```

But Its not any outout and stuck

I think may I need need to use fifo, so I change to

```
echo "" > output_txt;
zcat input.txt.gz | head -n 999999 |
   awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{print $13}' |
   tee >(st --percentile=2.5) >> output_txt |
   st --percentile=97.5 >> output_txt;
cat output_txt; rm output_txt
```

Its can running but output a long list of number, It seems that the program is calculating quantiles for each line

`input.txt` can be generated with

```
for ((i=0; i<999999; i++)); do
  number=$(awk 'BEGIN{print int(rand()*1000)/10}')
  echo $number >> input.txt
done
```

=====update======

As @ilkkachu comment, following command can work well

```
echo "" > output_txt;
zcat input.txt | head -n 999999 |
   awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{print $13}' |
   tee >(st --percentile=2.5 >> output_txt) |
   st --percentile=97.5 >> output_txt;
cat output_txt; rm output_txt
```

But it doesn't work when using fifo (still stuck)

Update:
as @Paul_Pedant

> A FIFO is a pipe. When it gets data up to some system limit, which may be 4096 bytes (POSIX minimum) or 64KB (typical Linux) or something else, the fifo blocks on write until some other process reads some of the data.

I think this can explain why stuck when using fifo

Comment: for one, the redirection in `tee ... >> output.txt | foo...` overrides the pipe, so the second command gets no input. You'd likely want `tee >(somecmd >> output.txt) | foo...`

Comment: Thanks, Its works on my second command, But it is not available when using fifo (it will still cause hang), can you help me explain why this is

Comment: A FIFO is a pipe. When it gets data up to some system limit, which may be 4096 bytes (POSIX minimum) or 64KB (typical Linux) or something else, the fifo blocks on write until some other process reads some of the data.

Comment: I got that, Thanks @Paul_Pedant